# ngRoute not working Angularjs App

Tags: angularjs

The following code brings up the right template fine, but it doesn't load any data and I think it's because of ngRoute but not sure.

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp', [
  'PremierLeagueApp.services',
  'PremierLeagueApp.controllers',
  'ngRoute'
]).

config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/teams", {templateUrl: "partials/teams.html", controller: "teamsController"}).
    when("/teams/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/team.html", controller: "teamController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/teams'});
}]);
```

The controller code looks like like this:

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp.controllers', []).
  controller('teamsController', function($scope, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.teamsFilter = null;
    $scope.teamsList = [];

    footballdataAPIservice.getTeams().success(function (response) {
        //Dig into the response to get the relevant data
        $scope.teamsList = response;
    });
  }).

  /* Driver controller */
  controller('teamController', function($scope, $routeParams, footballdataAPIservice) {
    $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.fixtures = [];
    $scope.team = [];


    footballdataAPIservice.getFixtures($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.fixtures = response; 
    }); 

    footballdataAPIservice.getTeam($scope.id).success(function (response) {
        $scope.team = response; 
    });


  });
```

and in the team.html I have this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures.fixtures">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{fixture.awayTeam}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Anyone see what could be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: so what does the template actually display to make you conclude that it loaded it correctly?

Comment: `fixtures.fixtures` ?  is it right ?

Comment: Can you check with a debugger if the teamsController is actually being executed? Just set a breakpoint at 
$scope.teamsFilter = null;
and check if the debugger holds there.

Answer (score 0):

Using DI, define the routes within the same module as the controller:

```
angular.module('PremierLeagueApp.controllers').
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when("/teams", {templateUrl: "partials/teams.html", controller: "teamsController"}).
    when("/teams/:id", {templateUrl: "partials/team.html", controller: "teamController"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/teams'});
}]);
```